# How to select the minimum no. from a list that is > 0?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, minimum

**How to select the minimum no. from a list that is > 0?**

I have tried:

- Using a list comprehension to weed out the non-positive
- Then do a `min()` on the filter list

I.e.

```
>>> x = (-3155, 611, 1284)
>>> min_x_more_than_0 = min([i for i in x if i > 0])
>>> min_x_more_than_0
611
```

There must be a better/faster way to do this. Imagine the length of X is 1,000,000,000 looping through the list is rather inefficient.

Comment: "Imagine the length of X is 1,000,000,000 looping through the list is rather inefficient." - you'd have to do that anyway even without the positivity constraint. You can get rid of the temporary list with a genexp, and you could shove all the loops into C with some more work, but you can't get rid of the loops entirely without restructuring your data.

Comment: Get rid of the `[` and `]`, which will convert the list comprehension into a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).  You won't have to build the entire list before you start searching it.  (You'll still have to search all of it eventually --- the least item could be one you skip.)

Comment: min(i for i in x if i > 0)

Comment: There really can't be a *much* better way: you *do* have to examine each list element, so anything you do will be O(N).  The above method iterates twice through the list, building a temporary list.  You could save some trouble by writing your own loop and avoiding the intermediate list, but that's about all you're going to get.

Comment: The faster way, would be to always keep track of the minimum value as the list grows. Another (more extreme) way could be to have a few threads each check a range of elements. Other than that, maybe black magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data is ordered, you can do this in O(log n) by using binary search.    Just [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) at 0 and index the neighboring element.

If the data is unordered, you can not do better than O(n) because you will have to inspect every element regardless.

You can push the entire computation into C code by using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(x)
>>> a[a > 0].min()
611
```